# Schema Diagram is not generating using Schemacrawler

Tags: schemacrawler

I am trying to generate a schema diagram using Schemacrawler but it is generating empty png file. I couldn't find the problem. Below are the command is used:

```
call java -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;lib/* schemacrawler.Main -driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl -user=certus2713 -password=certus2713 -schemas=certus2713 -tables="certus2713.NTH_USERS" tabletypes=TABLE -loglevel=CONFIG -infolevel=standard -command="graph" -Gdpi=300 -g=schemacrawler.config.properties -outputformat=png -outputfile=D:\dev\database-diagram.png %*

echo Database diagram is in database-diagram.png
```

Answer (score 0):

SchemaCrawler is behaving as designed. `-tables` takes a regular expression. You probably intended to say `-tables=certus2713\.NTH_USERS` Note that there are no double-quotes, and there is a slash before the dot to make it literal. Or, better still, use `-tables=.*\.NTH_USERS`

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)